# publicly available dataset of loan advertisement

Tags: data-request, finance

I'm looking for samples of advertisements by illegal money lending online, e.g. in comment sections of online forums etc. My intention is to use it as a training dataset to build a filter against such comments.

Does anyone know if there is an existing publicly available dataset for this?

Answer (score 3):

*This isn't exactly what you are looking for but...*

The US Consumer Finance Protection Bureau (CFPB) does publish consumer complaints on many different topics in what they call the Consumer Complaints Database.

> Each week we send thousands of consumers’ complaints about financial products and services to companies for response. Those complaints are published here after the company responds or after 15 days, whichever comes first. By adding their voice, consumers help improve the financial marketplace.

(excerpt from http://www.consumerfinance.gov/complaintdatabase/)

The data is downloadable is filterable and downloadable at https://data.consumerfinance.gov/dataset/Consumer-Complaints/s6ew-h6mp